# How can I split two containers vertically and let them be scrollable in Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm trying to accomplish the following:

[image: prototype]

I've got a fullwidth/set-height toolbar along top, with `flex-grow: 0` and a second container below with `flex-grow: 1`. This seems to work until I throw in the two scrollable containers that stick to the right of the application.

I can't seem to get the two "Scrollable" areas to do something similar to `height: 50%; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll`.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this layout with Flexbox?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xyo225z/)

And here is the example of html and css

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header> This is my header</header>

<div class="boxMain">main</div>
<div class="side">
<div class="box1">box 1</div>
<div class="box2">box 2</div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
header {
  min-height: 40px; 
  background: pink;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.side {
  width: 30%;  
  height: 375px;
  float: right;
}

.boxMain {
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 40%;
}

.box2 {
 width: 100%;
 background: blue;
 height: 40%;
}
```

And a picture for reference

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, one caveat, is it possible to have a 100% height on the container

Comment: Absolutely. The boxes height are based on % so regardless of the height of the container or in this case the wrapper the boxes should fill the page. 
Play with the values bro I am sure this will be  a great start for you. If you are building a website with this I strongly suggest you get use to using Bootstrap. It is fully responsive out of the box and pretty much everyone uses it so it is easy to find the answers you need with google. For example if you google 3 col row with bootstrap you will see tons of examples.